# Divs not showing up within AJAX .html file

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, external

I am using jQuery Tools to create a tabbed box that gets content via ajax. 
However, the content in the external .html file shows up but not anything that I try to put in  a div within that file.

Comment: Can you post some code? How do you do your ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... so, when you say "content in the external .html file shows up" I'm going to assume you mean "content that's not in a div" appears in the tab.

That means only one of two things:

1. You are applying CSS that is hiding that div. `#tab div` or something is set to be `display:none'` or `visibility: hidden` by default. So either the CSS needs updating or there's some missing JavaScript that's supposed to flip it to being visible.
2. The opposite of #1: your CSS is otherwise fine, but you have some JS (possibly even the plugin itself, mistakenly configured incorrectly) that is adding the styles to hide it.